# Steps for using RazorGenerator.MsBuild

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, msbuild, razorgenerator

I have tried to follow the steps from [Precompiling Razor views in ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stacktoheap.com/blog/2013/01/19/precompiling-razor-views-in-asp-dot-net-mvc-3/)

I can see the view cs files in the "`obj\CodeGen\`" folder

I changed the line

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\packages\RazorGenerator.MsBuild.1.5.0.0\tools\RazorGenerator.targets"/>
```

to

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\packages\RazorGenerator.MsBuild.2.4.4\tools\RazorGenerator.targets"/>
```

so it matches the version that is there.

There is NO "`RazorGenerator.targets`" file!

I have also read [the project's wiki pages](https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator/wiki) and anything I could find related to RazorGenerator on the net, but not sure what the next steps are suppose to be.

How do people actually use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never actually tweaked the project file to get the RazorGenerator.MsBuild to work. When I installed the package it handled that for me.

I did check and my import statement also contains a condition attribute

```
Condition="Exists('..\..\..\packages\RazorGenerator.MsBuild.2.4.4\build\RazorGenerator.MsBuild.targets')"
```

Maybe try unregistering and reregistering the package. Also, I am assuming that you do have a valid razorgenerator.directives file at the root of your templates folder. Mine contains the following settings but refer to wiki for options and effects.

```
@*  
Generator: Template
GenerateAbsolutePathLinePragmas: true
GeneratePrettyNames: true 
TrimLeadingUnderscores: true 
*@
```

You don't need to set the Custom Tool with the msbuild variant of RazorGenerator. Just compile and you will see the obj directory of your solution populate with a CodeGen | Templates folder. There you can view the .cs backing partial classes created by RazorGenerator.